# VBA issue with Find function

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'm trying to find the row of for a value within a certain range. This range is changing, so it is set up with variables. In the example below the range is set from row 1 to 441 and it finds the value in row 442. How can it find this outside the set range?

```
Set myDataFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myDataFolder & myFileName)
        If counter + n = 1 Then
            With myDataFile.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(nrlist(n), 1), Cells(nrlist(n + 1) - 1, 1))
            Set loc = Cells.Find(what:=list(j))
            If Not loc Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print (loc.Row)
                i = loc.Row
                Else
                i = ""
            end if
```

Comment: `i = ""` looks very weird.

Comment: `Find` should always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters, at a minimum.

Comment: `Debug.Print (loc.Row)` shouldn't have any parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, if you're finding a value outside the specified range, it might be because the `Cells.Find` method is not limited to the `With` block range you've defined. To ensure it searches only within the specified range, use `.Find` instead of `Cells.Find` inside your `With` block. Here's a compact correction:

```vb
Set myDataFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myDataFolder & myFileName)
If counter + n = 1 Then
    With myDataFile.Sheets(1).Range(myDataFile.Sheets(1).Cells(nrlist(n), 1), myDataFile.Sheets(1).Cells(nrlist(n + 1) - 1, 1))
        Set loc = .Find(what:=list(j))
        If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print loc.Row
            i = loc.Row
        Else
            i = ""
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Ensure `.Find` is prefixed with a dot to confine the search within the specified range. Also, specify the full path for `Cells` inside the `With` block to avoid referencing the wrong sheet.